# MVC client validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, javascript-globalize

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application that should accept the values in the German format. I tried to follow the instructions under [Adding Validation to the Model](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model) but I cannot find the required `globalize.culture.de-DE.js`.

I created a new project for test purposes only and installed the nuget package `jquery-globalize` and inserted the Script that is given on [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model). I also added a new model and the `DbContext`:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Double { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public string String { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created a CRUD Controller and tried to send data in the German format:

[image]

As expected the data is not recognized as valid without the *de-DE.js* file.

**What must I add to the Project to get this working?**

Comment: I faced similar kind of issue in one of my projects, got resolved by adding this file..dont know why

Comment: @barry but how can I get this file?

Comment: https://github.com/nje/jquery-glob

Comment: @barry As Rafael Xavier said it is only included in Version 0.1.3 - that was the Problem but it still does not work. See my comments at his answer

Answer (score 2):

Disclosure: I don't use ASP.NET nor NuGet.

Check the Globalize version that you have downloaded. You are using a deprecated version of Globalize (0.x). The latest 0.x branch on NuGet is 0.1.3, where you'll be able to find these files:

- https://github.com/jquery/globalize/tree/79ae658b842f75f58199d6e9074e01f7ce207468/lib/cultures

Comment: I used this PMC commands: 
`uninstall-package jquery-globalize
install-package jquery-globalize -version 0.1.3`
ok, now I get no error message but click the submit button does not work...the cursor is setted to the DateTime field and nothing other happen. What me confused is that the Double-Box is displayed as the first control but it does not get the focus. I think there is an error in my `date`-function:
`$.validator.methods.date = function (value, element) {
    Globalize.culture('de-DE');
    return this.optional(element) || Globalize.parseDate(value) !== null;
}`

Comment: My help is limited to point you to the correct Globalize or assist you further with Globalize 1.x questions. For everything else, it would be good to pull in people that wrote or have expertise on the other libraries.